# Replacing image on mousehover and at the same time moving it to its left

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image in my page. What I am trying to do is when any one hovers on that image I want to slowly move the image slightly to its left side and at the same time replace the image with another image. And on mouse out I want to get the previous image back in previous position.

I tried with the following code where I used `:hover` but its replacing really fast and not moving the image to its left enough.

Please check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chPrK/7/)

Could you please tell how to achive this using Jquery or CSS ?

```
<div class="fb-button"><a target="_blank" href="#"></a></div>
```

CSS

```
.fb-button a{
background-image:url(http://i33.tinypic.com/20svqkh.png); 
}

.fb-button a:hover{

background-image:url(http://i36.tinypic.com/n2b978.png); // replacement
}

.fb-button a, .twt-button a, .in-button a, .youtube-button a {
width: 34px;
height: 33px;
}


.fb-button a, .twt-button a, .in-button a, .youtube-button a {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Javascript for this.

Just use a negative margin and transition.

```
.fb-button a{
    background-image:url(http://i33.tinypic.com/20svqkh.png);
    /*transition*/
    -webkit-transition:margin 1s, background-image 1s;
       -moz-transition:margin 1s, background-image 1s;
         -o-transition:margin 1s, background-image 1s;
            transition:margin 1s, background-image 1s;
}
.fb-button a:hover{
    background-image:url(http://i36.tinypic.com/n2b978.png);
    margin-left:-0.5em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chPrK/6/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I was trying to create. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the move to the left, but you can achieve this and a longer duration when swapping images by using the transition-duration property. In the following demo I set it to 2 seconds. On the hover I set a right margin to move the image:

```
.fb-button a{
background-image:url(http://i33.tinypic.com/20svqkh.png);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}

.fb-button a:hover{

    background-image:url(http://i36.tinypic.com/n2b978.png);
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chPrK/5/

Comment: It will just do it instantly. As it is a visual effect, I'm not sure that matters a great deal. It’ll still be functional. If you must have the transition in older browsers, you can use a polyfill such as https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js Just detect support with something like Modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fade out one background and fade in another background all with the same object.  I'd suggest using separate objects like this:

```
<div class="fb-button">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/bkashlimited">
        <div class="fader1 fader"></div>
        <div class="fader2 fader"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And, this jQuery:

```
$(".fb-button").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".fader1").fadeOut();
    $(this).find(".fader2").fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".fader2").fadeOut();
    $(this).find(".fader1").fadeIn();
});
```

And, this CSS:

```
.fb-button {
    position: relative;
}

.fader {
    width: 34px;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
}

.fb-button .fader1 {
    background-image:url(http://i33.tinypic.com/20svqkh.png);
}

.fb-button .fader2 {
    background-image:url(http://i36.tinypic.com/n2b978.png);
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am trying to follow the social plugin in this site. http://www.bkash.com/ (on the right side). Do you think they are using the method that you posted? Thanks

Comment: @black_belt - if you wanted to do it the exact way that site does it, why didn't you put that in your question?  The way I've done it works and meets the criteria of your question as written - is there a reason you don't want to do it this way?  I don't know how bkash.com does it as there are many different ways to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.fb-button a{
    background-image:url(http://i33.tinypic.com/20svqkh.png);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.fb-button a:hover{
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    background-image:url(http://i36.tinypic.com/n2b978.png);
}
```

The warning here is that the `transition` property is still experimental, hence the vendor-specific prefix on it.

Different browsers use different prefixes. for example:

- Opera uses: `-o-transition`
- Firefox uses: `-moz-transition`
- Google Chrome uses the one shown above: `-webkit-transition`

These implement groovy new features, but are not standards compliant now and, though they might be soon, are not *guaranteed* to be in the future.

Comment: ...and, additionally, are guaranteed not to be supported very far in the past.